C++: define begin() and end() in abstract class
I ran into a problem while developing my optimization solver Uno.
I define an abstract class Collection that represents a set of integers I can iterate over: a vector, a numerical range (a set of integers {a, a+1, ..., b}), a symbolic concatenation of existing sets of integers, etc.
I have a function (say) get_bounded_variables() whose return type is const Collection&, which I can iterate over with a custom for_each function (see here):
problem.get_bounded_variables().for_each([&](size_t index) {
   ...
});

Different kinds of problems define get_bounded_variables() differently.
It does the trick, but I'd rather have a more classic syntax with range-based for loops.
Now, my problem is that, if I want to write something like:
for (size_t index: problem.get_bounded_variables()) {
   ...
}

I'd need to define begin() and end() functions for the abstract Collection, but its subclasses have different iterator types.
So, at that point I'm stuck, and I'm not sure this would be even doable. I just read about using free functions begin(const Collection&) and end(const Collection&), but I don't think this would help me.

make the functions virtual?

It looks like you need a type-erased iterator.

please show a [mre] within the question without relying on external links

@NathanOliver but which return type would I use for begin() and end()?

Technique you're looking for is called type erasure. Complete implementation for an STL-compatible type-erased iterator is lengthy due to many technical details, but for a for-based loop it's enough to implement operator*, operator++ and operator!=. Here is a minimal example:
class Iterator {
public:
    template<class It>
    Iterator(It it) : impl_(std::make_unique<Impl<It>>(it)) {}

    std::size_t operator*() const {
        return impl_->deref();
    }

    Iterator& operator++() {
        impl_->increment();
        return *this;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const Iterator& it1, const Iterator& it2) {
        return !it1.impl_->equal(*it2.impl_);
    }

private:
    class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() = default;

        virtual std::size_t deref() const = 0;
        virtual void increment() = 0;
        virtual bool equal(const Base&) const = 0;
    };

    template<class It>
    class Impl : public Base {
    public:
        Impl(It it) : it_(it) {}

        std::size_t deref() const override {
            return *it_;
        }

        void increment() override {
            ++it_;
        }

        bool equal(const Base& other) const override {
            return it_ == dynamic_cast<const Impl&>(other).it_;
        }

    private:
        It it_;
    };

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> impl_;
};

And here is an example of how you could use this type-erased iterator:
class Collection {
public:
    // ...

    virtual Iterator begin() const = 0;
    virtual Iterator end() const = 0;
};

class VecCollection: public Collection {
public:
    // ...

    Iterator begin() const override {
        return vec_.begin();
    }

    Iterator end() const override {
        return vec_.end();
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::size_t> vec_;
};

void print(const Collection& c) {
    for (std::size_t i : c)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}

int main() {
    VecCollection vc(/* ... */);
    print(vc);
}

Demo
